# How to get a newline character into a bash script?

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a bash script where there is a command

```
echo -e $(sort $1 | uniq -d)
```

When this script is run from the command line, all the rows come out in one line. How can I get an newline character into this script to get all the lines separated?

Comment: Why don't you just use `sort $1 | uniq -d`? Capturing the output only to pass it to `echo` is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to quote the echo to keep the format:

```
echo -e "$(sort $1 | uniq -d)"
```

See an example:

```
$ myvar="hello
> how
> are
> you"

$ echo $myvar     <--- unquoted, loses the format
hello how are you

$ echo "$myvar"   <--- quoted, keeps the format
hello
how
are
you
```